# Copying string into set<string> in lowercase?

Tags: c++, set, transform, lowercase, inserter

I have the following small and easy code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::string> in;
    std::set<std::string> out;

    in.push_back("Hi");
    in.push_back("Dear");
    in.push_back("Buddy");

    for (const auto& item : in) {
***        std::transform(item.begin(),item.end(),item.begin(), ::tolower);
***        out.insert(item); 
    }    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to copy all items of `in` into `out`.

However, with an in-place lowercase conversion, preferrably without an extra temporary variable.

So this is the required content of `out` at the end:

```
hi
dear
buddy
```

Please note, `const auto& item` is fixed, meaning I can't remove the `const` requirement (this is part of a bigger library, here is over-simplified for demo).

How should I do this? (If I remove the "const" modifier, it works, but if modifications are not allowed on `item`, how can I still insert the item into the set, while also transforming it to lowercase?)

Comment: Though it might not matter for your use, converting to lowercase one `char` at a time will not be correct for some languages other than English.

Comment: It's fine if it can be done withing ASCII range.

Comment: There is no way to do this in place if you can't get rid of the `const`.  A temporary will be required for you to do the transformation on before adding it to the set.

Comment: @Daniel this is very similar to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69977631/) about inserting lowercase strings into a `vector`. Why are you so determined to avoid temporaries before inserting?

Answer (score 1):

Note, you have to copy - since items in the original `in` container can not be moved into `out` container. The below code makes the copy of each element exactly once.

```
...
in.push_back("Hi");
in.push_back("Dear");
in.push_back("Buddy");

std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), std::inserter(out, out.end()),
               [] (std::string str) { boost::algorithm::to_lower(str); return str;}
              );    
return 0;
```

Comment: Lambda argument `(std::string str)` creates a copy, no?

Comment: Well, one **has** to have a copy, because one is expected to lowercase elements in `in`, without modifying original `in`. But this does not create more than one copy - the lower-case string is moved into the `set`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lambda function with transform, and you shouldn't have a const & to your strings or transform can't modify it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> in;
    std::set<std::string> out;

    in.push_back("Hi");
    in.push_back("Dear");
    in.push_back("Buddy");

    for (/*const*/ auto& item : in)  // you can't have a const & if your going to modify it.
    {
        std::transform(item.begin(), item.end(), item.begin(), [](const char c) 
        { 
            return static_cast<char>(::tolower(c)); 
        });

        out.insert(item);
    }

    return 0;
}
```